# How to create a symbolic link in a GDrive folder

Tags: symbolic-link, google-drive

I have a folder `$HOME/important_folder` that I want to have a backup of on Google Drive. The Google Drive is setup and mounted (under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=myUserName`)

In order to leave the folder where it is while also being backed up, I want to create a symbolic link on the Google Drive that links to the normal location.

So I write this in my terminal:

```
cd $LOCATION_OF_G_DRIVE

ln -s $HOME/important_folder $PWD
```

The error I get:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/run/user/1000/gvfs/google-drive:host=gmail.com,user=myUserName/important_folder': Operation not supported
```

So how do I achieve this task?

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this? How is this Google drive setup? Using online accounts? Use "edit" to add the info to your question.

Comment: There may be some clues in [this reference](https://www.maketecheasier.com/backup-files-to-google-drive-linux/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=17122020) to backup to Google-Drive

Comment: I prefer the `rclone` setup: https://rclone.org/drive/

Comment: @vanadium newest version. The GDrive is setup using the default Online Accounts functionality where I login with my Google account and enable Files.

Comment: Add this essential information to your post: use "edit". Anyway, you cannot create symbolic links on such mounted network volumes. It is a mount, not a synchronized folder.

Comment: Did you resolve this? Any way around the unsupported operation error?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the synchronism by GNOME is done via [`gio`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIO_(software)), which has the path `google-drive://username@gmail.com/` on a GUI file manager, but it is actually stored at `/run/user/...` on your GNU/Linux filesystem.

GIO (Gnome Input/Output) seems to not be optimized to work on terminal. You can even navigate through your directories by using `gio list -d google-drive://username@gmail.com/path/to/directory`, but it does not seem possible to make more sophisticated stuffs, such as symlink...

In nutshell, if you are like me and have a full-based terminal workflow, then maybe you had better to use [`rclone`](https://github.com/rclone/rclone), which is a terminal program that allows you to get a full control of your files from terminal. It is a little bit trickier to set this up, but it is much more powerful.